# RegEx strip everything except last character

Tags: regex, scriptlet

I have a line couple of several lines structured similarly to this and i want to remove everything except the last character. Can anyone advice on a regex everything i had found so far was to remove everything after Template and just end up with P,T,U

etc and for all these lines i want to end up with:
`<name>Doc_TEMPLATE_P
<name>Doc_TEMPLATE_T
<name>Doc_TEMPLATE_U`

Comment: 1. which language are you using? 2. what have you tried ? 3. why do you need regex? this is a task that could be done easily with string.length

Comment: java would be fine, i got this ^[^_]*_ but its doing the opposite of what i want instead of deleting after its deleting before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in teh comments above - you can (and should) use string.length to get only the last character - there's no added value to using regex in this case!

```
String str = "<name>Doc_TEMPLATE_P";
str = str.substring(str.length()-1);
System.out.println("str = " + str); // prints: "str = P"
```

Comment: I will mark the answer as correct but in my particular case it's not being applicable because i am using the regex functionality that's intergrated within another application. So a regex would have been better rather than a string str

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can do:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^(.*_).*", "$1P");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rD6fY3/11)

Comment: Did you check linked demo? It is returning `<name>Doc_TEMPLATE_P` for each line.

Comment: I will mark the answer as correct but in my particular case it's not being applicable because i am using the regex functionality that's intergrated within another application.

Comment: That is copy/paste of your comment of your comment on other answer but my answer is indeed using **regex only**

Comment: apologies for copying and pasting, I have seen from your demo it works however when i run it in my application it doesn't it will not return any values

Comment: I can only work on the problem posted. Is some code is not present or shown it is difficult to guess what's wrong.